# follower_type and followable_type in acts_as_follower gem giving different output in rails console and vs-code terminal

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-follower

I'm using

> gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch:
> 'master'

and I have 2 users, user1 is following user2. so, to check wheather user1 is following user2 I'm doing this
`u1 = User.find(1) u2 = User.find(2) u1.following?(u2)    # should return true`

when I run this in rails console it's giving
`Follow Count (4.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."blocked" = ? AND "follows"."follower_id" = ? AND "follows"."follower_type" = ? AND "follows"."followable_id" = ? AND "follows"."followable_type" = ?  [["blocked", 0], ["follower_id", 1], ["follower_type", "User"], ["followable_id", 2], ["followable_type", "User"]]`

and in vs-code console it's giving

`CACHE Follow Count (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."blocked" = ? AND "follows"."follower_id" = ? AND "follows"."follower_type" = ? AND "follows"."followable_id" = ? AND "follows"."followable_type" = ?  [["blocked", 0], ["follower_id", 1], ["follower_type", "ApplicationRecord"], ["followable_id", 2], ["followable_type", "ApplicationRecord"]]`

any solution ?

Comment: Notice the values in the vs code terminal 
It seems you are not passing the instance of `User` but the `Activerecord` collection

Comment: Check if you did `User.where(id: 1)` instead of `User.find(1)` in the vs-code terminal

Comment: No, I have use `User.find(1)`